# Distill not accessing style.css on website

Tags: html, r, r-distill

I am trying to upload a website created with distilling in rmarkdown. The home page looks correct but when I upload other pages to my website, it loses all of the style options I have applied. It looks correct when I open the HTML pages locally but not once uploaded. See below the issue. The home and about pages are correct, but the test is messed up. Has anyone seen this problem before?

https://centerforwashingtonareastudies.org/small_test/test.html

Comment: The links you have provided aren't there on the server.

Comment: When you put the webpage on the server,  you need to copy the contents of the `_site` directory to the folder for your website. [You can read more about that here.](https://rstudio.github.io/distill/publish_website.html)